# How can I call openDatabase within WebKit in a Windows based application?

Tags: browser, webkit

After creating a C# application for Windows that builds on top of the WebKit project I can successfully render HTML and make AJAX calls.  My application uses the `window.openDatabase` call.

This method seems to exist in a call to:

```
if (window.openDatabase)
```

will evaluate to `true`.  When the method is actually called to open the database, it will return `null` stating the database can not be opened.

I've found the following [link](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Webkitsdk-dev/2008/Apr/msg00027.html) for using this on WebKit for a Macintosh, but the same solution does not appear to be available for the windows build.

Does anyone know if this is available in the standard WebKit nightly builds for Windows and if so how to make this work?

Comment: Did you have any luck implementing it?

Comment: Kangax - No - I haven't.

My intent was to build a Windows simulator for a web application built for an iPhone.  I just ended up building a simulator into Safari